# zcat files in and not in gzip format

Tags: linux, pipe, zcat

I have all my Apache access log files as `access.log, access.log.1 access.log.1.gz` etc... What I want is to `zcat` all files in and not in gzip format and pipe them into an X program.

I know I can do: `zcat /var/log/apache2/access.log.*.gz | someapp...` but that will just work for `*.gz` and not the first two logs.

Any ideas will be appreciate it

Answer (score 26, accepted):

use zcat -f, it will copy uncompressed files as is

Answer (score 0):

For the specific use case of HTTP log server files, consider the `zmergelog` command (from the mergelog package). It additionally sorts the result of the merge chronologically.